# I have a Blazor server app. Is it possible to use client side java scripts in my blazor page? If yes how can do it in the easiest way?

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have built a Blazor server app as an intranet page in our company. I want to add some scrolling text like newsticker into my razor page. Is it possible to use client side java script for that? If yes how in the easiest way? If no, what is the alternative solution?

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/html-scrolling-text.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, you need to refer `.js` file in blazor `_Layout.cshtml` like

`<script src="dir/yourfile.js"></script>` in `body` tag. Then you can use it.